# Integration testing ASP.NET Web API 2 using HttpServer/HttpClient; no HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking to integration test a web service built on ASP.NET Web API 2.  Many things such as cookies, getting the current principal, etc. are done through HttpContext.Current.

I found the following resource on integration testing ASP.NET:
http://amy.palamounta.in/blog/2013/08/04/integration-testing-for-asp-dot-net-web-api/

This works great.  It spins up an in-memory host and combined with the automated schema generation of Entity Framework 6, setup and teardown are easy.

The problem comes in when things try and use HttpContext.Current to, as aforementioned, get cookies/etc.  It seems that when hosting in-memory using HttpServer, HttpContext.Current is always null.  This does make a little sense given there's no real request, but is a pain - it means the integration tests can't cover anything requiring anything from this property.

What can I do here?  It looks like very little of the data I'm using is present anywhere but HttpContext.Current, so am I just going to have to spin up full external instances on IIS?

Comment: You can always use HttpClient or RestSharp to invoke your Web API services directly from your tests.

Comment: Yeah, that works well, thanks.  I just need a simple way to set up and tear down instances of the Web API from within the tests.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your api using self host you have to avoid calling `HttpContext.Current` from a web api context. You can wrap it in something you can mock, like so:

```
public static class CurrentHttpContext
{
    public static Func<HttpContextBase> Instance = () => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
}
```

Then when you are creating your test server you could set the CurrentHttpContext to some fake `HttpContextBase`. For example using FakeItEasy (http://fakeiteasy.github.io/):

```
var context = A.Fake<HttpContextBase>();
CurrentHttpContext.Instance = () => context;
```

And then use this anywhere you need to access `HttpContext`:

```
var context = CurrentHttpContext.Instance();
// do what you need to do to httpcontext now like setting principal, cookies etc
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make it a unit test if I'm mocking anything?  I can't integration test things like session handling, user data separation, etc. if I'm having to make this by hand.

Comment: If you are still hitting the database I dont think this will make it a unit test. Maybe you could give an example of how you use HttpContext from a web api context?

Comment: I need to be able to test from a high, API-consumer level, that the authentication and authorization work.  Some of the tools in use (some of them third party) rely on HttpContext.Current to do this.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you are screwed :/ or you could change the third party libs to something that isnt so tied to HttpContext.Current. Like Thinktecture (http://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/24/resourceaction-based-authorization-for-owin-and-mvc-and-web-api/)

Comment: I think I'm going to have to do that yeah.  Thanks.